# Files, lists, new-lines, and append()?

Tags: python, list, file, split, append

I have a file with data:

```
ABC   acd   IGK  EFG

GHQ   ghq   acb  efg

IJK   ijk   gtt  ttg
```

I want to split its lines and take some data from each line and join them into a list. Like this:

```
a = ['acd', 'ghq', 'ijk']
```

So far I have done following.

```
li = [] 

with open('file.txt') as fl:

    for f in fl:

        f = f.split()

        li = li.append(f[2])
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Can someone please help me in completing the code?

Comment: Did you even [Google the error message](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=AttributeError%3A+%27NoneType%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27append%27)?

Comment: Methods of mutable objects like `list`s and `dict`s that change it in-place, such as `list.append()` and `dict.clear()`, don't return the object being changed. They effectively return `None`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do `li = li.append(f[2])`. You only need `li.append(f[2])`

`list.append` returns none which is why you are getting the error.